# What does getch() in Turbo C return? I am sure they are not ASCII values for keys pressed

Tags: ascii, turbo-c, getch

What does getch() in Turbo C return? I used it for initializing the arrow keys for a program, the values returned by getch() were 77, 80, 72 and 75 which are ASCII values for alphabets, which clearly indicates that they are not ASCII values. If they are not ASCII values, then what are they?

Comment: what makes you think that the arrow keys can't return alphabet chars? it all comes down to the terminal emulation.

Comment: can two keys have same ASCII values? This is my point.

Comment: thre's more than 255 different events that can be sent from a keyboard. that implies that some keystrokes are going to generate multi-byte outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getch()` provided in the non-standard `conio.h` returns an int:

```
#include <conio.h>

int     getch(void);
```

from the reference:

```
A single character from the predefined standard input handle is read and returned. 
The input is not buffered. If there is a character pending from ungetch 
(see section ungetch), it is returned instead. The character is not echoed to the 
screen. This function doesn't check for special characters like Ctrl-C.

If the standard input handle is connected to the console, any pending output in the 
stdout and stderr streams is flushed before reading the input, if these streams are 
connected to the console.

Return Value

    The character.

Portability

    ANSI/ISO C  No
    POSIX       No
```

Your problem with arrow keys is that they **are not single-byte characters**. In order to handle arrow keys you must handle **multi-byte** codes. The numbers you are getting are simply one of the two bytes of the key codes.

For an example of reading the codes see [**(How to read arrow keys) Cheat code in C programming (when inputted from the keyboard)**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21408837/how-to-read-arrow-keys-cheat-code-in-c-programming-when-inputted-from-the-key)

Comment: THANKS. But i want to see exactly what the keys return. How can i implement the multi-byte code?

Comment: Check link in answer.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee - Check the header file: `void  delline(void); int  getch(void); int  getche(void);`

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - yep. the header declares the return value an integer. but your reference says it is a character. Also, the name of the function shows that you can get characters. BTW, handling multi-byte codes requires multiple call of getch in Turbo C, so your example is useless.

Comment: @MatinLotfaliee are you just having a bad day? If it makes you feel better, feel free to continue inventing issues with the answer. I don't care. Since I provided no example, your snarky comment about it being useless is moot. I'm sure by this point in your understanding of C, you know that a 'character' is represented by numeric value where the terms are often used interchangeably. If you have issues with the reference, file a bug with `Turbo C` that is the source of the reference.

Answer (score 1):

getch () function returns two keycodes for arrow keys (and some other special keys), It returns either 0 (0x00) or 224 (0xE0) first, and then returns a code identifying the key that was pressed.

For the arrow keys, it returns 224 first followed by 72 (up), 80 (down), 75 (left) and 77 (right). If the num-pad arrow keys (with NumLock off) are pressed, getch () returns 0 first instead of 224.

So, you may do something like:

```
char ch = getch ();
if (ch == 0 || ch == 224)
{
    switch (getch ())
    {
    case 72:
        /* Code for up arrow handling */
        break;

    case 80:
        /* Code for down arrow handling */
        break;

    /* ... etc ... */
    }
}
```

Please note that getch () is not standardized in any way, and these codes might vary from compiler to compiler.

Comment: was this answer usefull?